# problems using the append() within a forloop

Tags: javascript, jquery

With an onclick="throw()" in one of my buttons and the value from a select tag, I want to spawn some dices in a div. so far I have this.

```
function throw() {
    var i = document.getElementById('quantity').value;
    for (var b = 1; b <= i; b++) {
        $("#dices").append("<canvas class="canvasstyle" id='dice"+b"' height='200' width='200'></canvas>");  
    }
}
```

I can't get the (yet still empty) dices to spawn. It keeps giving me
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list, somewhere within the forloop. Anyone who can see the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, first thing is you are trying to use double quotes inside double quoted text; you should be using single quotes. And you are also missing a plus sign as Festive Turnip said. So the line should be

```
$("#dices").append("<canvas class='canvasstyle' id='dice" + b + "' height='200' width='200'></canvas>");
```

Comment: Oh yeah. I missed the quotes :)

Comment: Tnx guys! As a real beginner in both html/css and js I totaly missed this.. I will remember atleast this quoting stuff from now on!

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a `+`.

`id='dice" + b "'` should be `id='dice" + b + "'`